# How to browse user generated folder in Openshift?

Tags: openshift

I made new app with PHP and JS, some users already uploaded the images on generated folder, I wanted to explore their images were submitted, but I did git pull, it won't download images

http://canvasuploader-powerupware.rhcloud.com/

Generated folder is http://canvasuploader-powerupware.rhcloud.com/user_images and it displays Not found.

Actually there are some images are saved on this folder, so how to explore this folder in Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

Anything your users upload to OpenShift will not be put into your git repository.  You will need to save the images into your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, and then create a symlink into your app-root/repo-runtime/php folder so that they will be web accessible if you need to display them.  if you want to download them to your computer, you can use the scp command, or you can use the rhc snapshot save command.